# Reset time picker

Tags: java, android, android-timepicker

I want to choose two different times when my time picker dialog shows up but after it saved the first time the time picker saves the hour that was previously picked and is set to choose minutes. Basically, I want to refresh the widget so that after I click to confirm the first time the time picker is set to choose hours instead of minutes.

I tried re-showing the popup so the widget is reset, and it works, but since I have some text views on the pop up layout with the margins set on programmatically the layout gets messed up and I wanted to make sure if there was an easier way to do it that don't need to reconfigure my layout.

The time picker is basically on a different layout than the one that is called from and its called as a dialog.

```java
Dialog mydialog;
mydialog.setContentView(R.layout.timepickerpopup);
```

`a[0]` is set to true on the on create method, outside the popup layout configuration

```java
done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && a[0]) {
            hour[0] = timePicker.getHour();
            min[0] = timePicker.getMinute();

            timefrom.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%02d:%02d", hour[0], min[0]));

            a[0] = false;
        }
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&  !a[0]) {
            hour[1] = timePicker.getHour();
            min[1] = timePicker.getMinute();

            timeuntil.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%02d:%02d", hour[1], min[1]));

            mydialog.dismiss();

        }
        else if (a[0]) {
            hour[0] = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
            min[0] = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

            timefrom.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%02d:%02d", hour[0], min[0]));

            a[0] = false;
        }
        else {
            hour[1] = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
            min[1] = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

             timeuntil.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%02d:%02d", hour[1], min[1]));

            mydialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using 2 different timepickers and toggling between them to get the 2 different hours I wanted.

```
TimePicker timePicker1 = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
TimePicker timePicker2 = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.timePicker2);
```

Here is the code if someone needs it:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && timePicker1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

                hour[0] = timePicker1.getHour();
                min[0] = timePicker1.getMinute();

                timefrom.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%02d:%02d",hour[0], min[0]));

                timePicker1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                timePicker2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                a[0] = true;

                if (a[0] && a[1]){
                    mydialog.dismiss();
                }

}else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&  timePicker2.getVisibility() == 
          View.VISIBLE) {

                hour[1] = timePicker2.getHour();
                min[1] = timePicker2.getMinute();

                timeuntil.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%02d:%02d",hour[1], min[1]));

                 if (a[0]) {
                    mydialog.dismiss();
                }else {
                    timePicker1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    timePicker2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                a[1] = true; 
}else if (timePicker1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

                hour[0] = timePicker1.getCurrentHour();
                min[0] = timePicker1.getCurrentMinute();

                timefrom.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%02d:%02d",hour[0], min[0]));

                timePicker1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                timePicker2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                a[0] = true;

                if (a[0] && a[1]){
                    mydialog.dismiss();
                }

}else {
                hour[1] = timePicker2.getCurrentHour();
                min[1] = timePicker2.getCurrentMinute();

                timeuntil.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%02d:%02d",hour[1], min[1]));

                 if (a[0]) {
                    mydialog.dismiss();
                }else {
                    timePicker1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    timePicker2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                a[1] = true;
}
```

On another part of the code I made it so you can choose what hour you are setting by pressing on its text (from / until) that's why I need a[0] to be true before dismissing the dialog (so both times will be set when finished unless you cancel).

As I'm new to this if anyone knows the answer to my question, or has some improvements for my code, it will be appreciated if it's shared here.